# getting incomplete output of categories webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

hey guys i want to scrape categories and subcatégories of this website https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110100-roues-velo-route.html using beautiful soup but all i get is the the first categories and subgategories
thank you for helping me
expecting output

```
[{'name': 'ROUES VÉLO ROUTE',
  'url': 'https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110100-roues-velo-route.html',
  'sub_categories': [{'name': 'Roue vélo carbone',
  'url': 'https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html'},
 {'name': 'Roue polyvalente',
'url': 'https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html'}]
}] etc..
```

this my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

SITE_URL = "https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110000-route.html"
HEADERS = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.materiel-velo.com/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8',
    'cookie': '_ga_5P0CXB07LK=GS1.1.1629112243.1.1.1629115778.0',
}
 response = requests.get(SITE_URL, headers=HEADERS)
 soupe = soup(response.content, 'html5lib')
 categories = []
 lvl1_1 = soupe.find_all(class_="subcategory")
  lvl11 = []
  for item in lvl1_1:
        lvl1 = {
             "name": item.text.strip(),
             "url": item.a['href'],
             "sub_categories": []
            }
        lvl11.append(lvl1)
        lvl2 = item.find(class_="subsubcategories").find_all('a')
        for elt in lvl2:
            lvl2 = {
                "name": elt.text.strip(),
                "url": elt.a['href'] 
                }
        lvl1['sub_categories'].append(lvl2)
    categories.append(lvl1)
    print(categories)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all categories/sub-categories + URLs, you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110100-roues-velo-route.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select(".categories .subsubcategories a"):
    main_category = a.find_previous(class_="category-title").a

    print(
        "{:<25} {:<45} {:<80} {:<60}".format(
            main_category.get_text(strip=True),
            a.get_text(strip=True),
            main_category["href"],
            "https://www.materiel-velo.com/" + a["href"],
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Roue vélo carbone         Roue vélo carbone, Alchemist                  https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/7336/roue-velo-carbone-alchemist
Roue vélo carbone         Asterion                                      https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2841/roue-velo-carbone-asterion
Roue vélo carbone         Black Inc                                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/5628/roue-velo-carbone-black-inc
Roue vélo carbone         Bontrager                                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/5493/roue-velo-carbone-bontrager
Roue vélo carbone         Campagnolo                                    https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2842/roue-velo-carbone-campagnolo
Roue vélo carbone         DT Swiss                                      https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2844/roue-velo-carbone-dt-swiss
Roue vélo carbone         Roue vélo carbone, FFWD                       https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/7452/roue-velo-carbone-ffwd 
Roue vélo carbone         Fulcrum                                       https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2847/roue-velo-carbone-fulcrum
Roue vélo carbone         Lightweight                                   https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/5820/roue-velo-carbone-lightweight
Roue vélo carbone         Mavic                                         https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2848/roue-velo-carbone-mavic
Roue vélo carbone         Roue vélo carbone, Most                       https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/7770/roue-velo-carbone-most 
Roue vélo carbone         Nix                                           https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/5546/roue-velo-carbone-nix  
Roue vélo carbone         Progress Cycles                               https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/6799/roue-velo-carbone-progress-cycles
Roue vélo carbone         Shimano                                       https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2849/roue-velo-carbone-shimano
Roue vélo carbone         Vision                                        https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2851/roue-velo-carbone-vision
Roue vélo carbone         Roue vélo carbone, Wilier Triestina           https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/7912/roue-velo-carbone-wilier-triestina
Roue vélo carbone         Zipp                                          https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2852/roue-velo-carbone-zipp 
Roue polyvalente          Bontrager                                     https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/5887/roue-polyvalente-bontrager
Roue polyvalente          Campagnolo                                    https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2824/roue-polyvalente-campagnolo
Roue polyvalente          DT Swiss                                      https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2825/roue-polyvalente-dt-swiss
Roue polyvalente          Roue polyvalente, FFWD                        https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/7453/roue-polyvalente-ffwd  
Roue polyvalente          Fulcrum                                       https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2826/roue-polyvalente-fulcrum
Roue polyvalente          Mavic                                         https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2827/roue-polyvalente-mavic 
Roue polyvalente          Progress Cycles                               https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/6712/roue-polyvalente-progress-cycles
Roue polyvalente          Shimano                                       https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2828/roue-polyvalente-shimano
Roue polyvalente          Vision                                        https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2829/roue-polyvalente-vision
Roue polyvalente          Roue polyvalente, Zipp                        https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110102-roue-velo-polyvalente.html                 https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2830/roue-polyvalente-zipp  
Blocage rapide roue       BBB                                           https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110108-blocage-rapide-roue-velo-route.html        https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2280/blocage-rapide-roue-bbb
Blocage rapide roue       Blocage rapide roue, Blackbearing             https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110108-blocage-rapide-roue-velo-route.html        https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/7918/blocage-rapide-roue-blackbearing
Blocage rapide roue       BMC                                           https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110108-blocage-rapide-roue-velo-route.html        https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/6318/blocage-rapide-roue-bmc
Blocage rapide roue       Campagnolo                                    https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110108-blocage-rapide-roue-velo-route.html        https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2281/blocage-rapide-roue-campagnolo


...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: To get output as a dict:

```py
out = {}
for a in soup.select(".categories .subsubcategories a"):
    main_category = a.find_previous(class_="category-title").a
    out.setdefault(main_category, []).append(a)

out = [
    {
        "name": k.get_text(strip=True),
        "url": k["href"],
        "sub_categories": [
            {
                "name": vv.get_text(strip=True),
                "url": "https://www.materiel-velo.com/" + vv["href"],
            }
            for vv in v
        ],
    }
    for k, v in out.items()
]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Roue vélo carbone",
        "url": "https://www.materiel-velo.com/c110101-roue-velo-carbone.html",
        "sub_categories": [
            {
                "name": "Roue vélo carbone, Alchemist",
                "url": "https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/7336/roue-velo-carbone-alchemist",
            },
            {
                "name": "Asterion",
                "url": "https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/2841/roue-velo-carbone-asterion",
            },
            {
                "name": "Black Inc",
                "url": "https://www.materiel-velo.com/s/5628/roue-velo-carbone-black-inc",
            },

...
```

Comment: thank you for your response but what i want as an ouput is like that 'sub_categories': [{'name': 'Freinage      Etriers de frein Freins à disque vélo route Disque vélo route Patins de frein vélo Porte-patins Plaquettes de freins route Kit de purge route/cx/gravel',
    'url': 'https://www.materiel-velo.com/c400213-freinage.html',
    'sub_categories': [{'name': 'Kit de purge route/cx/gravel'}]}]}, is it possible ??

Comment: @taniiit Can you please edit your question and put expected output there (with correct formatting)?